# LWC best Practice to call parent and child component

Tags: lightning-web-components, bestpractice

My question is bit difficult to explain but still I tried my best to explain it in the below playground

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pGoVYOyx/43/edit)

In my LWC project I have 3 step process and I divided it into 3 lwc pages

1. parent
2. child
3. grandchild

Now as shown in the above playground on a click of a button I change flags and display the pages accordingly, in real time I am saving  and retrieving data from the page in all three steps and I also have spinners on each page so that when data is coming and going to apex a spinner will appear.

The above structure works as expected but when data iterated on the page increased and if I click go to child button then it take  3 to 4 seconds of time to display the child page and coming back to parent takes even more time even though I am checking flags to show spinner(didn't add spinner on playground) but spinner comes only when a page is loaded and waiting from apex to retrieve the data from the database.

Even if buttons take time to respond at least a spinner should appear but the same is not happening.

Now my request is to please confirm if the above structure to show a three steps process is as per best practice or is there any better approach to display 3 LWC pages step wise step on click of a button as shown in the playground and if the button is taking 3 4 seconds of time to respond then how can I show the spinner on that period of time.

**ADDED**

In the next button If I write like below

```
nextPage = () => { this.showSpinner = true; this.step++; this.showSpinner = false; }
```

button takes 7 to 8 seconds to switch page but still no spinner comes

and if I change the button like below

```
 nextPage = () => { this.showSpinner = true; this.step++; }
```

Still spinner comes after 7 to 8 seconds, could you please suggest how can I cover the waiting time with spinner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason spinner may not be showing up is because your javascript calculations (like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/L0jnO1fB/4/edit) counting code) before switching page is taking 3-4 seconds. You need to check for such calculations.

Regarding the best practices, whether its 3 pages or 10 pages, what you are trying to implement is known as wizard and you can keep the code simple, maintainable and uniform by having only 2 buttons in the container page html and relevant JS. Below is the sample container code: (**[Playground Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pGoVYOyx/66/edit)**)

```
<div>
    <div>
        <template if:true={show1Step}>
            <c-parent full-data={fullData}></c-parent>
        </template>
        <template if:true={show2Step}>
            <c-child full-data={fullData}></c-child>
        </template>
        <template if:true={show3Step}>
            <c-grandchild full-data={fullData}></c-grandchild>
        </template>
    </div>

    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <template if:false={show1Step}>
        <lightning-button label={prevLabel} 
                            class="slds-float_left"
                            onclick={prevPage}>
        </lightning-button>
    </template>
    <template if:false={show3Step}>
        <lightning-button label={nextLabel} 
                            class="slds-float_right"
                            onclick={nextPage}>
        </lightning-button>
    </template>
</div>
```

JS:

```
export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track fullData;
    @track step = 1;

    nextPage = () => this.step++;
    prevPage = () => this.step--;

    get show1Step() { return this.step === 1; }
    get show2Step() { return this.step === 2; }
    get show3Step() { return this.step === 3; }

    get nextLabel() {
        if (this.show1Step) return 'Go To Child';
        else if (this.show2Step) return 'Go To Grand Child';
        else return 'Next';
    }
    get prevLabel() {
        if (this.show2Step) return 'Go To Parent';
        else if (this.show3Step) return 'Go To Child';
        else return 'Previous';
    }
}
```

---

**added**

In LWC you cannot change the data passed in `api` variables - so you cannot change the data in child components. You need to send the changed data in event to container component which will take care of modifying the `fullData` which will in-turn reflect in all child components and thus showing the latest data in all child components.

[Here is the reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_public)

> A component that declares a public property can set only its default
>   value. A parent component that uses the component in its markup can
>   set the component’s public property value. In our example, the
>   c-todo-item component can’t update the value of the itemName property
>   in the todoItem.js file.

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful example but could you please confirm few things in your example you assign full data to all 3 pages at once but what if I change any thing on full data at first page then will the same reflect at the 2nd page and if I change full data again on 2nd page then full data will be change for 1st and 3rd page or just 3rd page or none.

Comment: added in answer the correct way

Comment: Thank you so much, will try to implement the same in my project

Comment: I re structured my LWC project as per your suggestion above thank you so much for this wonderful idea, I am using refresh apex to avoid the stale data and it was working as expected in previous structure but now when I update data on 1st page click on next page  and come back to first page again I see older data instead of the updated one I added console logs and I can see the updated data in console log but I really wonder from it is getting the staled data, could you please suggest on it?

Comment: Since it is using if:true, it will unrender the DOM if the condition is false and when you load that component again, it will fetch the data from server instead of the one modified previously (if using LDS/record-forms). [THIS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pGoVYOyx/67/edit) is how you can maintain the DOM state using styling. If this is not yet clear, pls create another question with details

Comment: But when I update the data on my page I click on update button and then it updates the data in the database if it fetches the data from server then it should fetch the updated data not the staled data, in console log I see the updated data the same data I send to the parent component and console log on parent shows the updated data but when I switch the pages I don't know from where it gets the staled data and the 2nd time console log shows the staled data too and If use slds show hide then it wont unrender as you said then will it affect the page performance right?

Comment: DO NOT use slds-hide if you are already saving the data to database before going to next step. And this should not really happen if you are using wire services. It seems like issue is somewhere in the code - can you create new question with relative code and if possible playground link?

Comment: Sure I will try :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101965/discussion-between-gs650x-and-salesforce-sas).

Comment: I have updated my question regarding the spinner, could you please take a look for once?

Comment: @salesforce-sas I want to confirm something: generally speaking, when you're structuring nested components you want to pass down properties and functions to child components and handle events in parent components because events bubble from child components to parents right? Thanks again.

Comment: @AtlasCan, yes right.

Comment: @salesforce-sas sorry to bother you, but could you please look into the below question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288418/i-do-not-have-prod-access-in-my-org-i-want-to-know-can-we-edit-lightning-compon