# I do not have Prod access in my org. I want to know can we edit Lightning component in Production?

Tags: code, production

Can we edit  Lightning component in production?

Answer (score 1):

Lightning (meaning: Aura) Components can be changed in Production, however it is not recommended because it would cause discrepancies between any and all Sandboxes that were created before the change on Production. Of course you could recreate the changes on your Sandboxes or refresh them, but that is something that is often forgotten or would require some manual work.

I myself have also created a Lightning Component on Production once to add a Tutorial to a Customer Portal in the past.

What you can't change without deployment is anything directly in connection with Apex, so "ApexPage" (Visualforce Pages), "ApexClass" and "ApexTrigger"

I cannot say if LWCs can be edited on Production, because they cannot be edited in the Developer Console.

Comment: Thanks for the info..